# How to post composite key data parameters with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have data like this on server side.

For UserImagesTable, these are my parameters

```
 {

                 "status" : false,
                 "id" : {
                    "userId" : 1,
                    "imageId" : 1
                     }
```

I need to post data through alamofire and retrofit.

I tried like this: I created one model class for userImages Table and one more model class for userImages.id table

My model classes are:

```
       class UserImages

       {
        var status : Bool? = nil
        var id : ImagesId? = nil

       func toJson() -> [String:Any] {

       return[

        "status" : status as Any!,
        "id" : id as ImagesId!
        ]
        }
       }


      class ImagesId
      {
       var userId : Int16? = nil
       var imageId : Int16? = nil

       func toJson() -> [String:Any] {

       return[
        "userId" : userId as Any!,
        "imageId" : imageId as Any!,
        ]
        }
        }
```

Then my Alamofire

```
               let ImageParams = UserImages()
               let ImageIdParams = ImagesId()

    ImageIdParams.imageId = 2
    ImageIdParams.userId = 3
    ImageParams.status = true
    favouriteVideoParams.id = ImageIdParams.toJson()-->this line coming some error like -->Cannot assign value of type '[String:any]' to type ImageId?

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ImageParams.toJson(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: Defines.Constants.Headers)
```

What I'm doing for post, is this approach correct or not? If it's possible give me some idea about retrofit post also.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

For Alamofire, your .toJSON functions aren't really required a simpler solution would be that you create a parameter variable in your function that shapes the parameters with pre-defined keys and variable values given via the function, this would look something like this:

```
func postUserImageTable(with status: Bool?, and userImagesId: ImagesId?) {
   let url = "your url"
   let parameters = [
       "status": status!
       "id": [
            "userId": userImagesId?.userId
            "imageId": userImagesId?.imageId 
      ]
   ]
   Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
}
```

as per the official documentation of Alamofire ([Alamofire Post with JSON encoded Params](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters))

For Retrofit you can make use of the @body tag to POST pojo classes to your server. So if you have equivalent java classes as you showed in Swift, being this:

```
public class UserImage {
  private Boolean status;
  private ImagesId imagesId;

  //constructor
  //getters and setters
}

public class ImagesId {
  private int userId, imageId;

  //constructor
  //getters and setters
}
```

then you can add this call to your retrofit service

```
@Post("your/post/url")
Response postUserImageTable(@Body UserImage body);
```

And you can use this in your call with retrofit:

```
Call<Response> call = Service.postUserImageTable(new UserImage(false, new ImagesId(1,2));

call.enqueue(New Callback<Response> {
  //obligatory overrides from retrofit
})
```